# Passing PHP session variables through header redirects

Tags: php, redirect, session-variables

I'm writing a PHP login system for a robotics team I'm on. The flow of the login system is as follows.

1. On the index page, it checks to see if $_SESSION['log_info'] is set to 'true' and if so, displays content for members. If it's false it displays a login page.
2. Then, after login, it goes to login.php which connects to the database and checks if the user credentials match and such. It stores $_SESSION['log_info'] to a range of values that correspond the events on the login.php page.
3. It then redirects to the index page which reads $_SESSION['log_info'] (thus knows the status of the login.php page) and does actions for the different values.

*My problem is that the session variables are not being passes through the redirect on the login.php page. They are null.*

Things I have checked and that are working:

- I have checked that they are being set, and they are. (I can echo them on the login.php page.)
- I also know the redirects work because I can change where the header statements go and it all functions fine.
- I also know that the PHP session cookie stays constant throughout the ordeal, so thats not it either.
- I have sessions_start(); on all my pages.

---

**Here is the code for the two pages:**

*index.php*

```
<?php // this is first line of page
session_start();

// If user is not logged in, sets $log_info == 'false'
if (!isset($_SESSION['log_info']) || $_SESSION['log_info'] == '' || $_SESSION['log_info'] == '0') { $_SESSION['log_info'] = 'false'; }

function get_banner() {
  // Switch statement for all cases of $log_info... Usually displays banner to user...
  switch ($_SESSION['log_info']) {
    case 'true':
      echo '<div class="banner">You are logged in!</div>';
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      break;

    case 'false':
      echo '<div class="banner">Please login below.</div>';
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      break;

    case 'error':
      echo '<div class="banner">Your username or password do not match.</div>';
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      break;

    case 'acc_fail_username':
      echo '<div class="banner"><b>Account creation failed:</b><br/>Your selected username already exists. Please pick a different one.</div>';
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      break;

    case 'acc_fail_parm':
      echo '<div class="banner"><b>Account creation failed:</b><br/>One or more of your entry fields were invalid. Please try again.</div>';
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      break;

    case 'acc_success':
      echo '<div class="banner">Your account was successfully created! Login below.</div>';
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      break;

    default:
      $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
      //die('Something went wrong internally. Please stay calm while we fix it');
  }
}

?>

<?php get_banner(); ?>

<b>Login:</b>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

*login.php*

```
<?php // this is first line of page
session_start();

// Connect and verify connection
$con = @mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM FRC4096users WHERE     username='".$username."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$salt = $row['salt'];

if ($row['passwordhash'] === hash('sha512', $password . $salt)) {
  $salt = hash('sha512', rand());
  mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET salt='". $salt ."' WHERE     username='".$username."'");  // Resets salt on login for security
  mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET passwordhash='". hash('sha512', $password .     $salt) ."' WHERE username='".$username."'");  // Resets salt on login for security
  $_SESSION['log_info'] = 'true';
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: /');
  die();
} else {
  $_SESSION['log_info'] = 'error';
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: /');
  die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Theres no real need for the session_write_close(), thats not your problem, but its kinda useless here

Comment: I added it in just to make sure it wasn't the problem. I will take it out eventually

Comment: best course of action is put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of both pages and look for signs of errors

Answer (score 0):

You should try a few things:

1. Check if all domains are the same. Sessions change when you change your domain.
2. Take a look at the temporary folder where sessions are stored in. Try monitoring to see if something is wiping the data from the files.
3. Search your project files for any `session_destroy()` you may be unaware of.
4. Remove `session_write_close()` from your files, since this is automatically executed in the end of parsing and your script is short.
5. Try changing error reporting level using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before starting the session.
6. Maybe a `print_r($_SESSION)` in all pages can help you to find where the data is going away.

This may help you detect where your error is.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What if you did this....

```
<?php // this is first line of page
  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['log_info']){  header('Location: /login.php');die();} 
  else {

 switch ($_SESSION['log_info']) {
  case 'true': echo '<div class="banner">You are logged in!</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['log_info']);
    break;

  case 'false':
    echo '<div class="banner">Please login below.</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['log_info']);
    break;

case 'error':
  echo '<div class="banner">Your username or password do not match.</div>';
  unset($_SESSION['log_info']);
  break;

case 'acc_fail_username':
  echo '<div class="banner"><b>Account creation failed:</b><br/>Your selected username already exists. Please pick a different one.</div>';
  $_SESSION['log_info'] = '';
  break;

case 'acc_fail_parm':
  echo '<div class="banner"><b>Account creation failed:</b><br/>One or more of your entry fields were invalid. Please try again.</div>';
  unset($_SESSION['log_info']);
  break;

case 'acc_success':
  echo '<div class="banner">Your account was successfully created! Login below.</div>';
  unset($_SESSION['log_info']);
  break;

default:
  unset($_SESSION['log_info']);
  break;
  }
}
?>


 <b>Login:</b>

 <form action="login.php" method="post">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
 Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Then on your login page, have this...at the top....rest is the same....

```
<?php // this is first line of page
   session_start();
   session_unset();
 //rest of code
```

Comment: I just tried the same code on my personal web server with a copy of database using my host and the code worked PERFECTLY. URGH. Now I have to figure out what settings are wrong with my team's server... Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe try running <?php phpinfo();?> and see if sessions are enabled?

Comment: Ah, I did and session.use_only_cookies was On for working code, while Off for nonworking code. I will try to get the webmaster person to change the setting and see if it fixes the problem!